# Custom font not working in visual studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio

My custom font is working in MS Word but it is not working (showing in the list but not recognizable and effective) in visual studio 2012. Does anyone has any idea why. The font is True type.

Comment: There are some parts of VS's user interface that require a monospaced font. Could tht be related to your problem?

Comment: No, I am using it in a SSRS text box. The other custom fonts are working but one is not.

Comment: John, were you ever able to solve this issue?  I have a similar issue with Visual Studio and haven't been able to resolve it via anything I've found online.

Comment: No I was not able to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found to handle this is to avoid attempting to add the custom font to visual studio or Windows.  I've seen a lot of posted on how to add it and none of them work well especially with a web application.  The best solution which I've deployed many times is to use strictly CSS.  I've used the below method many times and it's worked perfectly.  I did run into some cross browser issues.  Be sure to point the source to the path and file name of where your font file is located.  Here is a good link explaining how to resolve some cross browser issues:  http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2009/12/webdev/adventures-with-font-face

```
@font-face {
    font-family:"NameOfFont";
    src: url("NameOfFont.ttf") /* TTF file for CSS3 browsers */
}

.newFont
{
   font-family: 'NameOfFont';
}
```

To be even more complete to use this using IE.  You must convert the TTF to EOT format.  There are several converters out there.  Below is the CSS that worked for that fix.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontName';
    src: url('FontFile.eot');   
}
```